# Как сделать неявную переадресацию поддомена в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать так, что бы если человек перешёл по любому поддомену, то происходила неявная переадресация на папку site.ru/directory/

Comment: Неявная - имеется ввиду чтобы не было редиректа, а сервер направился в папку /directory?

Comment: Да. И, что бы, если например человек перейдёт по poddomen.site.ru/profile/ то это было site.ru/directory/profile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA] # скрываю index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сервера `apache` необходимо подключить модуль `mod_rewrite`.

`.htaccess` для корневой директории должен выглядеть примерно так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).domain.ru [NC]
RewriteRule .* /directory/$1 [L]

# ...
# остальные правила
# ...
```

И не забудьте положить `.htaccess` в `/directory/`

Comment: Можно по подробней? Не получилось

Comment: Сделал у себя рабочий вариант. Обновил ответ

Comment: htaccess добавил, но почему то ничего не работает. Не изменилось ничего